# Is there a JS function which sorts a list by a function value

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to sort a list filled with lists by their 0th index.

In Python, this would look like

```
l = [[1, 0], [5, 1], [6, 2], [3, 2]

l.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
#l is now [[1, 0], [3, 2], [5, 1], [6, 1]]
```

What would this look like in Javascript?

Comment: `l.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])`

Comment: There is no direct comparison method in javascript, but you can define a custom sort function to manually compare the first element of each set

Answer (score 1):

Array sort method does the same job:

```js
const arr = [[1, 0], [5, 1], [6, 2], [3, 2]];
arr.sort((a,b) => a[0] - b[0]);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function which takes a function fro getting the value for sorting.

```js
let l = [[1, 0], [5, 1], [6, 2], [3, 2]],
    fn = x => x[0],
    sort = fn => (a, b) => fn(a) - fn(b);

l.sort(sort(fn));
    
l.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```